# Is there a central limit theorem for i.n.i.d. variables when normalised by inconsistent variance estimate?

Tags: independence, convergence, central-limit-theorem

I am wondering whether there exists a central limit theorem for the following situation. Consider the sum of normally distributed variables $\epsilon_i$ with unequal variances according to $\epsilon'Z$ where $\epsilon$ is an $n\times 1 $ vector and $Z$ is an $n \times 1$ deterministic vector.

If we now form the sum and pseudo-normalise the expression via $\epsilon'Z/\sqrt{\epsilon'\epsilon}$, what would happen in terms of convergence? Under i.i.d. $\epsilon_i$, we'd have a CLT but if we relax that and let the $\epsilon_i$ be i.n.i.d. or heteroskedastic, what exactly changes?

In essence, I wish to study the limiting distribution of
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\sum_i z_i \epsilon_i}{\sqrt{\sum_i \epsilon^2_i}}
\end{eqnarray}

One useful fact may be that it can be shown that $\epsilon'\epsilon/n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\sigma^2_i + O_{p}(1/\sqrt{n})$ where $var(\epsilon_i)=\sigma^2_i$.

Comment: Last assertion is definitely incorrect.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the role played by $Z$ here. ? Are you asking something different than about the limiting distribution of ? $$\frac {\sum \epsilon_i }{ \sqrt {\sum \sigma^2_i}}$$

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos thank you so much for your question, yes exactly, it should be no different from the fraction you wrote but the weighting by the $z_i$ does show up in my problem so I wasn't sure whether this adds to complexity or makes it easier perhaps? The crux of the matter seems to be that under heteroskedastic $\epsilon_i$ we don't have a Liapounov CLT because the variables are not adequately normalized but rather by an average variance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
$$\frac{\sum_i z_i \epsilon_i}{\sqrt{\sum_i \epsilon^2_i}} = \frac {\sqrt{\sum_i z_i^2\epsilon^2_i}}{\sqrt{\sum_i \epsilon^2_i}}\frac{\sum_i z_i \epsilon_i}{\sqrt{\sum_i z_i^2\epsilon^2_i}} = \frac {\sqrt{(1/n)\sum_i z_i^2\epsilon^2_i}}{\sqrt{(1/n)\sum_i \epsilon^2_i}}\frac{(1/\sqrt n)\sum_i z_i \epsilon_i}{\sqrt{(1/n)\sum_i z_i^2\epsilon^2_i}}$$

Now, since your variables are independent normals, their weighted sum is a normal random variable already for finite samples, it doesn't have to wait until infinity.

What you need to have is that $(1/n)\sum_i z_i^2\epsilon^2_i$ converges in probability. Then apply Slutsky's theorem. The limiting distribution will be normal, but not *standard* normal.

Comment: Thank you so much @Alecos Papadopoulos ! May I just ask, how can I study the limiting distribution further, for example, what will happen to the variances?

Comment: @Hirek The process of determining whether the expression converges in distribution will also give you the asymptotic variance.